# Classifying boundary conditions when PDE is given on the whole space.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am being asked to classify the boundary conditions for: $u_{x} + u_{y} = 0$ such that $u(x,y)=1$ whenever $x=y$. I have only learned about three different boundary conditions: Dirichlet, Neumann, and Eigenvalue. But it doesn't appear to be any of these.

Based on the fact that the solution to this PDE is constant on the characteristic lines having slope one, I can see that the condition basically gives the value of the PDE on the characteristic line $y=x$. Maybe that lets us classify the boundary conditions, but since there is no domain specified, I'm not sure how I'd go about classifying this boundary value problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition $u(x,x)=1$ $\forall x$ is a substitute for a boundary condition. 
In fact, in can be interpreted as a Dirichlet boundary condition on the boundary of $\mathbb R^2 \setminus\{ (x,x), \ x\in\mathbb R\}$.
From this the solution can be constructed from characteristics.

In other instances of pdes on unbounded domains, one often adds integrability conditions, which force a certain decay of $u(x)$ for $|x|\to \infty$. And thus act as some kind of boundary condition at infinity.